# 2008 Macbook not recognizing bootable USB

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, startup, ssd

I've recently bought a new SSD for my 2008 13" Macbook, wanted to perform a clean install of El Capitan, however after creating the bootable USB I am unable to boot from it. I plugged the USB into the Macbook, held Opt while powering it on. Only a blank screen with a cursor appeared. I also tried resetting the NVRAM with Cmd + Opt + R + P with no results. I also tried Cmd + R which resulted just with flashing file & question mark.

I created the USB using TransMac on my Windows PC following a guide below:

https://www.wikigain.com/create-bootable-usb-installer-for-mac-transmac/

I tried creating several USBs and even burnt a DVD, none of them were registered on the Macbook. I also tried creating a Yosemite USB and DVD, no results whatsoever.

I have no other Mac to try the USB on, but from what I've read on other threads, some of the newer computers have no problem recognizing it.

I also tried burning a DVD with a different program called UltralISO, still no results.

Edit: Checked the Disk Manager on Windows, the USB has the EFI partition (see screenshot below).
[image: Disk Manager]

Edit 2: Watched a video on YT with similar problem. Guy solved it using an older USB stick. However there shouldn't be a problem when I used a DVD instead? Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JClNt8w3fPo&t=7s

Edit 3: I'll try and do a Mavericks clean install. Maybe it'll work??

Edit 4: So, I spent my whole night shift formating some old USBs I found in the office (no luck there). But! I successfully managed to boot a Mavericks installation using an old HDD with SATA adapter. However I am now stuck a the . Also one of the USB managed to boot with Snow Leopard in it, but the problem persists (https://youtu.be/6KEmzxJc-sM).

Comment: Windows shouldn't be able to read a Mac disk, so something went wrong at the formatting stage. Needs to be GUID [which Windows calls GPT] with an HFS+ partition [Which Windows cannot natively read or write, unless TransMac is providing translation… but if it was it would know it's HFS]. Launch TransMac rather than Windows' own disk manager & see what it thinks the drive is formatted as.

Comment: Windows doesn't read the USB, just shows the partitions in Disk Manager. TransMac correctly recognizes HFS partition with EFI.

TransMac screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/UmIomUT.png

Comment: Sorry, then I'm out of ideas. I'd say an 08 would be right on the cusp for being able to boot from USB [I have a couple of old 08 Mac Pros that simply will not, yet 09s that will]… but it should boot from the DVD otherwise.

Comment: It seems to suggest that the 110.63Gb partition is NTFS. Do you still have the old hard drive, Can you boot from that, either internally, or externally, just to check that *something* can boot.

Comment: Also, which 2008 MacBook is this? The Aluminium one can boot to El Cap, but the White ones can only boot to Lion 10.7.

Comment: @benwiggy - that's the Windows boot drive Disk 0, nothing to do with the USB stick, mounted as Disk 2. Your 2nd point about which MB is rather more pertinent.

Comment: The 2008 MacBook can in fact boot from USB, however, it has to be a bootable OS X or macOS USB.  I’ve installed Lion (10.7.x) on White MacBooks via USB.

Comment: It's the 2008 aluminium with upgraded RAM to 8 GB, so El Capitan should work fine and should boot from the stick. The Disk 0 partition is indeed my Windows SSD which has nothing to do with the USB. ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have the original HHD, I already wiped it and used it in another computer.

Comment: So, I spent my whole night shift formating some old USBs I found in the office (no luck there). But! I successfully managed to boot a Mavericks installation using an old HDD with SATA adapter. However I am now stuck a the 

Comment: What do you mean? Did the Mavericks disk boot to the desktop or not? If you can boot to Mavericks, then you should be able to install El Cap on the SSD from there.

Comment: Nope, Mavericks didn't boot to desktop, I just used the HDD like a USB for clean install. I got stuck at the prohibition symbol.

Comment: So, to recap, this Mac won't boot to any disk? That suggests the problem is not the disk. At what stage was the prohibition symbol?

Comment: @benwiggy - check the video https://youtu.be/6KEmzxJc-sM. Seems like it was starting to boot from the USB, but then the prohibition symbol appears.

Comment: Hooray!! I successfully booted into Tiger installation.

Comment: Tiger? That's impossible. The earliest software for that Mac is 10.5 Leopard. Now that you've got it booted, check the model and OS version in "About This Mac".

Comment: Lion, my bad, I am all too confused with the animals now. ‍♀️ Nevertheless, just upgraded to El Capitan and working fine!